# Using Sub-domain with multiple related apps within Laravel 5.2

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I'm working on a project for an E-commerce site. I have three modules viz. Vendor, Admin and Customer.
What I want to achieve is to handle all these modules using same Laravel instance but different app folders. I tried to get hints from google but couldn't find anything related to Laravel 5.2.
Right now I'm using the sub-domains by redirecting the user to Specific laravel Instance depending on the sub-domain entered via `index.html.`

Here is my index.html:

```
<?php

$url = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];

$parsedUrl = parse_url($url);

$host = explode('.', $parsedUrl['path']);

$subdomain = $host[0];

if($subdomain == "seller")
    require __DIR__.'/../blog/bootstrap/autoload.php';
else
    if($subdomain == "admin")
        require __DIR__.'/../admin/bootstrap/autoload.php';
    else
        require __DIR__.'/../customer/bootstrap/autoload.php';

if($subdomain == "seller")
    $app = require_once __DIR__.'/../blog/bootstrap/app.php';
else
    if($subdomain == "admin")
        $app = require_once __DIR__.'/../admin/bootstrap/app.php';
    else
        $app = require_once __DIR__.'/../customer/bootstrap/app.php';


$kernel = $app->make(Illuminate\Contracts\Http\Kernel::class);

$response = $kernel->handle(
    $request = Illuminate\Http\Request::capture()
);

$response->send();

$kernel->terminate($request, $response);
```

But I want to achieve this functionality by using same Laravel instance, unlike I'm doing right now. Also, it would be really helpful if someone can point out if my method is good enough to be deployed in  production.

Comment: Why use multiple app folders if you can use only one app folder?

Comment: Though the Modules are related few things like authentication will be different for all of them

Comment: Then why not just use different UserController / AuthenticationController but same app directory?

Comment: Yes. I could have done that. But I have already developed the modules and deploying them in few days. But if applied MultiAuth now I would need to make changes at many places.

Comment: I will move my project to this approach in future. But as the deployment date is near I don't want to do it now

Comment: @HuzaibShafi thanks for your suggestion I have moved my application on single laravel instance using multi-auth